# drawing a nxn gameboard in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program which asks the user for the size of an n x n gameboard. I want my program to print out a gameboard of that particular size.

Here is what my code looks like. I have the main function draw_gameboard() and defined two separate functions for the horizontal and vertical lines respectively. What I'm trying to figure out is the code which specified that the execution of each respective function occurs one after the other. That is to say, I want the program to call the function that draws the horizontal lines and then execute the function that draws the vertical lines and so on and so forth.

Here is what I have so far:

```
number = input("pick a value for the nxn game board ")

def draw_gameboard(number):
    if int(number) <= 0:
        print("invalid choice")

    else:
        def draw_horizline(number):
            print(" --- " * number) 

        def draw_vertline(number):
            print(" | " * (number + 1))


print(draw_gameboard(number))
```

Comment: Okay, let us know if you have a question about your code when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing things up - don't define functions inside the `else` clause or inside other fuction, define it like this:

```
def draw_horizline(number):
        print(" --- " * number)
def draw_vertline(number):
        print(" | " * (number + 1))
def draw_gameboard(number):
    if int(number) <= 0:
        print("invalid choice")
    else:
        for _ in range(number):
            draw_horizline(number)
            draw_vertline(number)

number = input("pick a value for the nxn game board ")
draw_gameboard(number)
```

Now you have 3 seperate function - one that draw horizontal line, one that draws vertical line and one that calls the first two fucntions in a loop (because you want to alternate horizontal and vertical lines for the required amount).
Also, when you write `print(draw_gameboard(number))` that means that you are printing whatever the `draw_board` function returns, but this function does not return anything, it just draws on the screen, so the `print` is redundent.

Comment: So after correcting some of the value errors in the above (namely int(number)) I got it to print something. Only issue is that it is only printing the lower diagonal half of the board.

Comment: Try to use some low values for `number` e.g. 3 or 4. You will see the entire output and you will also see that you need to better align the vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change

```
print(draw_gameboard(number))
```

to

```
draw_gameboard(number)
```

Since `draw_gameboard()` already has a bunch of `print()`s, you don't need the `print()` here. You only do this when a function returns a value and then you want to print out that value.

Next, don't use `def` inside another `def`. This defines a nested function. There are some very good uses for this, but those are more advanced than where you are right now.

So change

```
    else:
        def draw_horizline(number):
            print(" --- " * number)
```

to

```
    else:
        print(" --- " * number)
```

and similarly for the vertical line.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the functions for drawing horizontal and vertical lines, you should move the `def` for each function outside the `draw_gameboard()` function. Then you need to actually call these functions so that they do their job.

Side note: even with these changes, your logic to draw horizontal lines isn't quite right. I expect the horizontal lines will be too close. But you will see better once you make these changes so your board actually draws. Then you can make adjustments from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing three things:
defining a function (def draw_hor...
calling a function  (draw_hor...
providing a value to a function (number = 10 ...

The following code shows how your code could work.

```
def draw_horizline(number):
    print(" -- " * number) 

def draw_vertline(number):
    print("|   " * (number + 1))

def draw_gameboard(number):
    if int(number) <= 0:
        print("enter a number greater than 1")
    else:
        draw_horizline(number)
        draw_vertline(number)
       

number = 10
draw_gameboard(number)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help